# How to Use Spark to Shuffle big files?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

I have a 20G text file and I want to shuffle its lines. Due to the limitation of local memory I want to do it on spark. Can someone tell me how to do it?

P.S. I considered using key-pair `(random.random(), line)`, so spark will sort by `random.random()` as it saves the file. I do not know does it work.

Comment: Spark is an in memory framework, so not sure I understand how it'll help you

Comment: @cricket_007 it could work out, but there are certainly better ways to achieve what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Python, and assuming your text file RDD is called `lines`, try this:

```
shuffled_RDD = lines.map(lambda line: (random.random(), line)).sortByKey.map(lambda line: line[1:])
```

This is not tested, but the logic should work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to read the file as a dataframe and then use `orderBy`;

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
val shuffledDF = df.orderBy(rand())
```

This will randomize the order of the dataframe rows. After this, simply save as a text file again.